# Self adjoint operator.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex inner product space and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Prove that $T$ is a self adjoint if and only of $(T \alpha | \alpha )$ is real for every $\alpha$ in $V$.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem ?

Comment: Why so many votes (4 till now) for closing this topic? Is it very obvious to answer. Is 4 distinct answers available?

Comment: I assume that the votes to close are because that you did not share any thoughts on the problem, didn't give context, didn't mention what you know or don't know on the subject and etc' - you only wrote the question as-is (and in a mannered way, but that does not mean that just stating the problem is OK). By the way, closing is more "on hold" untill the post improves, not a closed for good kind of close.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Actually I did not understand how to solve it and so I could not show anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $v \in V$. Then $$\begin{align*} \langle T v , v \rangle − \overline{\langle T v , v \rangle}  &= \langle T v , v \rangle − \langle v , T v \rangle \\ &= \langle T v , v \rangle − \langle T^* v , v \rangle 
\\&=\langle (T −T^*)v,v \rangle\end{align*}$$

If $\langle Tv,v \rangle \in R$ for every $v \in V$, then the left side of the equation above equals $0$,
so $\langle (T − T^*)v,v⟩ = 0$ for every $v \in V$. This implies that
$T − T^* = 0$ (since $\langle T v , v \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V  \implies T = 0$), and hence $T$ is self-adjoint.

Conversely, if T is self-adjoint, then the right side of the equation
above equals $0$, so $\langle Tv,v \rangle = \langle Tv,v \rangle$ for
every $v \in V$. This implies that $⟨Tv,v⟩ \in R$ for every $v \in V$.

Source: *Linear Algebra Done Right*, Sheldon Axler.

Comment: That's exactly the argument I came up with myself, and was just about to type up!

Comment: Sorry! I immediately recognized this problem from my Adv Lin Alg course last spring, and happened to be sitting next to my bookshelf.

Comment: Hey, no need to apologize, I've beat a few people to the punch as well around here! ;)

Comment: @Aedwards Thank you for helping me. Also thanks for your source.